# explain the working of this circuit

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck-boost

[image]I'm basically trying to understand how this Dc to Dc step-up converter work. please help me.[![dc-dc step-up voltage converter 1v-9v][2]][2] I need to design a DC DC step up converter using bjts. Except the dc voltage of 1v, I'm not supposed to use any kind of external voltage. I need to get an output voltage of 5v. Please don't suggest me to use mosfets as I'm restricted to use them in this case. Explain me how the switching takes place and how the inductor charges and discharges. I think switching takes place at Q2 but not sure how. I don't have a perfect explanation for that. Please explain me the entire switching process.

Comment: Ask a specific question and we'll help you.

Comment: The schematic is very badly laid out. Where did you get it? What do you understand and where are you stuck?

Comment: what is the working of Q1 and Q2? I think Q2 acts a switch.explain me the whole circuit,

Comment: I believe they act as switches. I want to step up the dc voltage from 1V to 10v using bjts in particular without using MOSFETs. I'm not supposed to use any kind of pWm .

Comment: do you understand it may not work with an inverted PNP?  stick to circuits that work and are well documented, and never make an illogical (non-conforming) drawing unless its a paper napkin

Comment: The main purpose of a transistor is to behave like an electric switch, so you're right about that. So in that case, what do you think it's switching here? (I'm asking questions to help you find an answer, AKA Socratic questions) How do boost converters work? Why do they need a duty cycle, inductor, capacitor, etc.? How is the duty cycle determined and what is the circuit behavior on each cycle?

Comment: I think q2 is switching here. obviously, for a step up converter, we must have an inductor. in the case of mosfets we can use the pwm to turn it on/off to make the inductor charge and discharge accordingly

Comment: There's too little information about your previous understanding here. You should update the actual question with details about your current reasoning. Don't answer people in the comments because those are just temporary.

Comment: Like a cris-cross dual RC astable Osc, this is a variation using an LC relaxation Osc with a diode instead and 2 caps and 1 L instead of 2 RC's  and 2 Q.'s The sawtooth eventually goes unstable and the output decays with the real characteristics with a light 1M load

Comment: I think the question should be re-opened by mods maybe @pipe with a couple minor edits by the Op to show level of comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Q1 PNP reversed gives unity current gain so the 10nF doesn't overdrive Q2 when it switches ON.

It is a positive AC feedback loop from two inversions of base to collector current and thus can become an astable oscillator with sufficient gain of Q2.

A sawtooth voltage on Q1b is expected until V2b conducts with pulses Q1 off only to repeat the cycle.

The Q2c output current from L1 is instantly switched thru the Schottky diode to continue the inductor current pulling up the voltage in typical boost fashion.

Here is an improvement

[image]

Comment: can you please explain how to calculate the frequency of switching?

Comment: I wonder if any other expert here can do this?  perhaps  pipe, Bimpelrekkie, Bruce Abbott, winny, Edgar Brown ??  I might answer if it is re-opened, but that's up to you to correct the question and make it more specific ( to appease the Mods )

Comment: e.g. start with my image pasted into your question and ask the above question, then you will figure out how it works (OK?)